# Web app for erasing some words on a photo

Tags: web-apps, image-editor

Is there a program online that can erase some words on a photo and keep it clean, and without making a screen capture?

Comment: sorry, what do you mean 'keep it clean' and 'without making a screen capture'? Do you want to upload a picture without taking a screenshot??